# Document is inserted twice into MongoDB when using Mongoose create method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am having below schema in my API which gets details of username and the products he added to the cart.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb connection').then(()=>{
console.log('DB connection is successfull');});

const AutoIncrement = require('mongoose-sequence')(mongoose);

const cartSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
cartId : {
    type : Number
},
username : {
    type : String
},
productsInCart : [{
    productId : {type : Number,required : true},
    productName : {type:String},
    quantity : {type:Number}
}],
statusOfCart : {
    type : String,
    default : 'Open'
}},{ timestamps: true });

cartSchema.plugin(AutoIncrement,{id : 'cart_seq',inc_field : 'cartId'});
let cartModel = mongoose.model('carts',cartSchema);
module.exports = cartModel;
```

As you can see in the above code I am also using the mongoose-sequence to make cartId as a auto-incremented field.

Now, I have a POST request which gets the below JSON in request body and adds it to the cart collection in the MongoDB using the create method.

> {
> "username":"admin",
> "productsInCart":
> [
> {
> "productId":1,
> "productName":"Watch",
> "quantity":4
> },
> {
> "productId":2,
> "productName":"Phone",
> "quantity":5
> }
> ]
> }

The code inside the Route Handler for the POST request in Express API would look something like this

```
let ctMod = new cartModel();
ctMod.username = req.body.username;
ctMod.productsInCart = req.body.productsInCart;
let insCartData = await cartModel.create(ctMod,{new:true});
if(insCartData.length > 0)
{
  return res.status(200).json({
       message : `New items got inserted into the cart with the ID : ${insCartData.cartId}`,
       data : insCartData
       });
 }
```

The above code inserts two entries into the collection like below instead of one

> {
> "statusOfCart": "Open",
> "productsInCart": [],
> "createdAt": "2021-01-04T15:25:35.188Z",
> "updatedAt": "2021-01-04T15:25:35.188Z",
> "cartId": 13,
> "__v": 0
> },
> {
> "statusOfCart": "Open",
> "productsInCart": [
> {
> "_id": "5ff332a891aa170b60a21ea9",
> "productId": 1,
> "productName": "Watch",
> "quantity": 4
> },
> {
> "_id": "5ff332a891aa170b60a21eaa",
> "productId": 2,
> "productName": "Phone",
> "quantity": 5
> }
> ],
> "username": "admin",
> "createdAt": "2021-01-04T15:25:35.210Z",
> "updatedAt": "2021-01-04T15:25:35.210Z",
> "cartId": 14,
> "__v": 0
> }

can you help me understand why there is duplicate entries in my db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are using `cartModel.create(ctMod,{new:true});` inorder to create a new entry to your collection.

You can simply do like this :

```
let ctMod = new cartModel();
ctMod.username = req.body.username;
ctMod.productsInCart = req.body.productsInCart;

try{
let insCartData = await cartModel.save();
  return res.status(200).json({
      error:false,
       message : `New items got inserted into the cart with the ID : ${insCartData.cartId}`,
       
      data : insCartData
    
   });
 }
catch(err){
console.error("error inserting data", err);
return res.status(500).json({error:true, message:"Something went wrong :("}).

}
```

**UPDATE :**

Reason for the duplicate entry is that you are passing the `{new:true}` flag in the create API. It's used to return the updated document in the `findOneAndUpdate` method. But in create/save, the mongoose return the data by default. Hence the flag is not needed.If you omit the flag, duplicate entries can be prevented.

Also, as you are using the `create` method to save the new entry, you need not create an instance of the `cartModel`. ie.,

`let ctMod = new cartModel();`

can be just

`let ctMod = {}`

Hope it helps!

Comment: using save instead of create did avoid the duplicate entry...do you know why create inserts duplicate entries